# Formatting of MySQL data using python

Tags: python, mysql

I have file that reads from a MySQL database and pulls the data into a list as such:

[(Decimal('3.6813'),), (Decimal('3.6816'),), (Decimal('3.6804'),), (Decimal('3.6794'),), (Decimal('3.6789'),), (Decimal('3.6791'),)]

Is there a way I can either just pull the numbers and not the Decimal part so it is in the format [3.6813,3.6816,3.6816,3.6816] or a way I can convert it to that format?

The .sql file that reads from the database is:

```
SELECT calc_star_rating
FROM GBAndroidRating2015
WHERE country=%s
AND report_date>'20141231'
AND report_date<'20150201'
AND platform='Android'
AND version='all';
```

And the .py file that utilises this code is:

```
import utildb

def main():

#set config
local_db_cnf='./config/mysql_connect.json'
sql_get_ratings='./config/get_ratings_local_db.sql'

#get latest date from local database for user agg data
ratings_data=utildb._get_data_local_db(sql_get_ratings,['GB'],utildb._create_cnx_json_local_db(local_db_cnf,'appstore'))
print ratings_data
return

if '__main__' == __name__:
main()
```

Comment: It depends on your behavior of function `_get_data_local_db` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the mysql data stored in a variable, it can be converted to a float format using:

```
from decimal import *

ratings_data = [(Decimal('3.6813'),), (Decimal('3.6816'),), 
                (Decimal('3.6804'),), (Decimal('3.6794'),),
                (Decimal('3.6789'),), (Decimal('3.6791'),)]

adjusted = [float(i[0]) for i in ratings_data]  # The important line
```

Where `adjusted` is:

```
[3.6813, 3.6816, 3.6804, 3.6794, 3.6789, 3.6791]
```

Comment: Thank you, made it look very easy. I just stuck "adjusted = [float(i[0]) for i in ratings_data]" into my code and it works thank you once again!

Comment: Yup, that's the bit you really needed, I just provided some context.